# How can i get an array of all elements with a certain class added

Tags: jquery, arrays, select

Here's what I'm trying to do:
Currentrly i have a list of tags, which will sort some data from database on click, is there a way to get a list of elements which are choosed?

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="tag tagId_4">Tag 4</a>
<a href="javascript:;" class="tag tagId_3">Tag 3</a>
<a href="javascript:;" class="tag tagId_2">Tag 2</a>
<a href="javascript:;" class="tag tagId_1">Tag 1</a>
```

And here is what have done at this moment:

```
$('.tag').click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('class');
            id = id.substr(10);
        $(this).addClass('tag_selected');
    });
```

How can i get a list of id's of all links with class tag_selected?

Comment: `$('.tag_selected')` will return collection of elements. Not clear what you mean by `list`. Please put a little more effort in explaining your issues. What do you consider an `id` based on what is shown?

Comment: Look, i have some tag links, those tags have a class with their id(tag tagId_4, tag tagId_3 and so). When I click on a link, I add a class called 'tag_selected', i need to store somehow all elements which have class 'tag_selected' and then i want to get their id's from their class(array(4, 3, 2, 1)) so i can work with those in mysql query.

Comment: *I want to get an array of all elements which have this class*: So what's the problem with `$("a.tag_selected")`? This will give you a jQuery set of all such elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery selector `$()` will return an array of elements if the query matches more than one element, so:

```
$('.tag_selected');
```

will return them all.

In terms of the design of your implementation, I'd switch to using the actual id attribute of the `<a>` tag to store the id of the element.

You can use something like this to retrieve the `id` number of each selected element to an array:

```
var ids = $('.tag_selected').map(function() {
  return $(this).attr('id').match(/.+_(.+)/)[1];
}).get();
```

That regular expression will basically match anything up until an underscore, then capture anything after the underscore and return it. The `[1]` at the end is accessing the second item in the array returned from the `match` function (which is the first captured string).

Comment: Thanks for the `.attr('id').match(/.+_(.+)/)[1]` thing, didn't knew about it :)

Comment: Thanks :) I've updated my answer to return what you want (hopefully, I didn't test it). The `match` code is used in some list drag and drop libraries that I've worked with, and `map()` is much more succinct than creating an array, looping over elements and adding items to the array. http://api.jquery.com/map/

Comment: How do i get the results of a .map()? I'm trying this code right now `var ids = $('.tag_selected').map(function() {
    $(this).attr('id').match(/.+_(.+)/)[1];
};

console.log(ids);`

Comment: I updated the answer to include `.get()` at the end which returns an array rather than a jQuery collection. Also noticed a typo! (missing bracket) so try the updated code.

Comment: Still not working, added the missing bracked and tried to alert(ids), getting an enmpty alert.

Comment: Lol! Sorry, I'm a ruby programmer so I forget about explicit returns. I've updated the code to `return` the id for each iteration of `.map()`. I've also created a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nfg4xb8f/

Comment: Thanks, this is much better than an array.

Comment: You're welcome :) check out the jQuery docs as there are a few utility methods that it provides for stuff like this. The underscore library is also quite useful for manipulating arrays etc...

Answer (score 1):

```
function getListOfSelectedElements() {
    var list = [];

    $(".tag_selected").each(function (index,  element) {
        var id = $(element).attr("id");
        if (id) {
            list.push(id);
        }
    });

    return list;
}
```

Comment: Why not use `.map()`? and also, this doesn't take into account the text in the `id` preceding the number if he wants to send it back to the server for use in MySQL.

Comment: @Brendon Muir: the tags suggested a need for a JQuery-based solution. For instance: I don't know if there is a need for this to work on IE 8, where Array.prototype.map would not work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe by using "$(.tag-selected).each(someFunction)" and let the function do something for an individual element containing that class.